# OpenCV MouseEvent Closing Program

Tags: c++, opencv, mouseevent

I'm trying to use OpenCV Mouse Events but for some reason it is closing my program.

The code that I'm using.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void CallBackFunc(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata)
{
 if  ( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )
 {
     cout<<"Deseja Salvar o ponto  (" << x << ", " << y << ") ? (1) sim (0) nao" << endl;
     int option;
     cin>>option;
     if(option == 1)
      cout << "O ponto (" << x << ", " << y << ") foi salvo com sucesso!" << endl;


 }

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
Mat img = imread("pic.png");
 if ( img.empty() ) 
 { 
      cout << "Error loading the image" << endl;
      return -1; 
 }

 namedWindow("My Window", 1);
 setMouseCallback("My Window", CallBackFunc, NULL);
 imshow("My Window", img);
 waitKey(0);

  return 0;

}
```

The problem is: It works fine for some time (It can get about 10 points) and then simply close the program. I want to get an undefined number of points .Does anyone know what's going on?

Please Help!!!!

Comment: Does it exit normally? you might be accidently pressing the keyboard?

Comment: The program will terminate when you press any keyboard key because of `waitKey(0)` statement. So the program will quit as soon as user starts entering data `cin >> option`

Comment: Just add these to your code  `while(1){
 if(waitKey(0)==27) break;
 }` and check whether it's exiting while `esc` key pressing.